# using array.filter method how can i check a value from the object of the array and return different value from the same object of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter, observable

In the code, I am getting an array of objects from the observable and I want to check a value from an object of that array and return a different value from the same object if the condition is satisfied. How can I do that?

here is the code:

```
  addresses$ = this.addressData$.pipe(map((addressData)=>{
    addressData.filter((data)=> {data.deviceType === 1})
  }));
```

the data object is coming as

```
data : {
  deviceType: 1,
  value: "1911 Ralph st, CA - 900099",
  unit: 11
}
```

I want to check if the `deviceType` is 1 then return the value "1911 Ralph st, CA - 900099" to `addresses$`. And I want to use the filter method to do this.

Comment: what will happen if the `filter` condition does not meet ?

Comment: `filter` only takes an array, and removes any element from that array that doesn't cause the filter function to return true. It has nothing to do with "returning values", it does rather the complete opposite: it removes values.

Comment: and if deviceType is not 1 then?

Comment: If you want to end up with an array just containing addresses of type == 1, just start with the filter and then map just the value..

Comment: @krunal you are almost there inside that condition just return the new object you want

Answer (score 0):

First you filter the data with Array.filter, then you change the data with Array.map.

```
[1,2,3].filter(x => x > 1).map(x => x * 10)
```

doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array